# TrigReduce applied to certain terms? Finding coefficients of trig terms

Tags: fourier-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

I have an expression that involves trig functions of `t` and `y`. I would like to find the coefficients of `Cos[t], Sin[t], Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t] ...` and the constant term independent of `t`. I can get the terms in `t` and `y` separated by using `TrigExpand` however this then leaves me with trig expressions like  `Cos[t]^2`. To reduce these to terms in `Cos[n t]` etc. I have to apply `TrigReduce` to them but NOT to the terms involving `y`. TrigReduce does not have a second parameter to tell it to just reduce terms in say `t`. Can we make one?

My workaround is to use `FourierTrigSeries` guessing the highest trig multiple I need (here 5 but I don't want to guess) and then to use `Coefficient` to find the individual terms and the constant term. This is a bit long.  Are there other ways?

Thanks

Here is a simple example. I will need to do more complex examples.

```
e1 = -(Cos[t] - E^(-(y/Sqrt[2])) Cos[t - y/Sqrt[2]])^2 + 
   1/2 ((E^(-(y/Sqrt[2])) Cos[t - y/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2] - (
      E^(-(y/Sqrt[2])) Sin[t - y/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[
      2]) (-(Sqrt[2] - 2 y) Cos[t] + 
      Sqrt[2] E^(-(y/Sqrt[
        2])) (Cos[t - y/Sqrt[2]] - E^(y/Sqrt[2]) Sin[t] + 
         Sin[t - y/Sqrt[2]])) ;

e2 = e1 // TrigExpand;
e3 = FourierTrigSeries[e2, t, 5];
trigs = Flatten@Table[{Cos[n t], Sin[n t]}, {n, 5}];
coffs = Coefficient[e3, #] & /@ trigs;
const = e3 - coffs.trigs;
```

The coefficients are

```
coffs // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the constant terms is

```
const
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A sanity check gives

```
Simplify[e1 == const + coffs.trigs]

(* True  *)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:
These are the transformation rules:

```
rules = {Cos[t]^n_Integer :> TrigReduce[Cos[t]^n], 
  Sin[t]^n_Integer :> TrigReduce[Sin[t]^n], 
  Times[a_, Cos[t] , Sin[t], c_] :> a*c*TrigReduce[Cos[t] Sin[t]]};
```

With these rules

```
Collect[e2 /. rules, {Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t]}]
```

yields

[image]

You might want to simplify the coefficients of the sin(2t) and cos(2t) as follows:

```
MapAt[Simplify, 
 Collect[e2 /. rules, {Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t]}], {{7, 2}, {8, 2}}]
```

giving the following

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Good idea, write my own rules. Thanks.

Comment: I know that this post was written long time ago, but I would like to add a correction to the `rules` defined above.

It is better to write the last element of the them as
`Times[a___, Cos[t] , Sin[t]] :> Times[ a, TrigReduce[Cos[t] Sin[t]] ] ` 

For example, only in this form the rules will render the expressions like  $2 \sin x \cos x$ into $\sin 2 x$, while the original rules will leave such input untouched

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use [`FourierCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierCoefficient) to compute the general term:

```
f[n_] = FourierCoefficient[e1, t, n];
f[n] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{8} \left(-2+e^{-\frac{(1-i) y}{\sqrt{2}}} \left(2+(1-i) \sqrt{2} y\right)\right) & n=-2 \\
>  \frac{1}{8} \left(-2+e^{-\frac{(1+i) y}{\sqrt{2}}} \left(2+(1+i) \sqrt{2} y\right)\right) & n=2 \\
>  \frac{1}{8} \left(e^{-\frac{(1+i) y}{\sqrt{2}}} \left((1+i) \sqrt{2} y+(1-i) e^{i \sqrt{2} y} \left(\sqrt{2} y+(1+3 i)\right)+(4-2 i)\right)-4
>    e^{-\sqrt{2} y}-4\right) & n=0
> \end{cases}$

We can then recover the [`Sin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin) and [`Cos`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cos) coefficients as follows:

```
sin = Simplify @* ComplexExpand /@ Simplify[I(f[n]-f[-n]), n>0];
sin //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}} \left(\left(\sqrt{2} y+2\right) \sin \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\sqrt{2} y \cos
>    \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right) & n=2 \\
>  0 & \operatorname{True}
> \end{cases}$

```
cos = Simplify @* ComplexExpand /@ Simplify[f[n] + f[-n], n>0];
cos //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}} \left(-2 e^{\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}}+\sqrt{2} y \sin \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\left(\sqrt{2} y+2\right)
>    \cos \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right) & n=2 \\
>  0 & \operatorname{True}
> \end{cases}$

```
zero = Simplify @* ComplexExpand @ f[0];
zero //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{4} e^{-\sqrt{2} y} \left(-2 \left(e^{\sqrt{2} y}+1\right)+e^{\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}} \left(\sqrt{2} y-2\right) \sin
>    \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+e^{\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}} \left(\sqrt{2} y+4\right) \cos \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$

Using [`FourierSinCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierSinCoefficient)/[`FourierCosCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierCosCoefficient) to obtain the general term doesn't work quite as well, but we can use them to check the above results:

```
(sin /. n->2) == FourierSinCoefficient[e1, t, 2]
(cos /. n->2) == FourierCosCoefficient[e1, t, 2]
```

> True
>
> True

Comment: This is a good way of getting a general term. One problem is how to find how many terms there are and `FourierCoefficient` is certainly a good way of doing this. Although you have to recombine terms this may be the best method. I am not sure what happens if there is no general term. It seems a shame that one has to go to the effort of taking a Fourier transform when all that is needed is to do algebra to find the trig terms. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also with this:

```
e1 = -(Cos[t] - E^(-(y/Sqrt[2])) Cos[t - y/Sqrt[2]])^2 + 1/2 ((E^(-(y/Sqrt[2])) Cos[t - y/Sqrt[2]])/
  Sqrt[2] - (E^(-(y/Sqrt[2])) Sin[t - y/Sqrt[2]])/
  Sqrt[2]) (-(Sqrt[2] - 2 y) Cos[t] + 
 Sqrt[2] E^(-(y/Sqrt[2])) (Cos[t - y/Sqrt[2]] - 
    E^(y/Sqrt[2]) Sin[t] + Sin[t - y/Sqrt[2]])); 
CoefficientList[FourierTrigSeries[TrigExpand@e1, t, 5] /. {Cos[a_*t] :>  x^a, Sin[a_*t] :>  z^a}, {x, z}]
```

[image]

After obtaining the Fourier series you can transform the trig polynomial to a usual polynomials and then extract the coefficients.

I think you can save steps.

Comment: Interesting idea. Are there dangers in replacing a trig with an exponent? I will try this out. Thanks